# How to disconnect BLE device in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am creating an iOS app in Swift 5 and can connect to my BLE device but can not disconnect. I found a function `cancelPeripheralConnection` on the apple developer website but Xcode does not seem to recognize it. When I type `CBCentralManager` the function appears and I can fill in the value to be passed but I keep getting an error.

Below are some picture of the code and the problem.

[image]

Comment: Copy/paste code, not screenshot. And the issue is that you are using the method as it were a class method while it's an instance one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```swift
centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(yourPeripheral)
```

Your manager is an object used to manage discovered or connected remote peripheral devices. So you have to use it to disconnect a peripheral.

Comment: I have tried to do this method but I get the same error when I run it in my viewWillDisapear() method. I had to call centralmanagerDidUpdateState and have a disconnecting if statement